# Find and replace substring beginning and ending with new string java

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to find and replace a substring beginning with string 'sps.jsp' and ending with substring 'FILE_ARRAY_INDEX=12'.

Following is my string content

> beginning with strings............[sps.jsp]..anything between.. [FILE_ARRAY_INDEX=12] ending with some strings....

Below is my code

```
 Pattern r = Pattern.compile("sps.jsp[\\s\\S]*?FILE_ARRAY_INDEX=12");
 Matcher m = r.matcher(InputStr);
 if (m.find( )) 
 {
   System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group() );
 }
```

I'm not able to get my pattern and replace it with a new string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to [**`String::replaceAll`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) with this regex `sps.jsp(.*?)FILE_ARRAY_INDEX=12`

```
String inputStr = "....";//your input
inputStr = inputStr.replaceAll("sps.jsp(.*?)FILE_ARRAY_INDEX=12", "[some string]");
```

**Outputs**

```
beginning with strings............[some string] ending with some strings....
```